# Custom control to access H2 Database (JDBC) from .Net environment

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, jdbc, h2

Our application needs to communicate via a H2 database (JDBC) from .Net Framework (WinForms). I have experience with C#/.Net Framework programming, but I need some guidance with respect to the following issues:

- The UI controls correspond mostly to the database tables/columns so using databinding makes sense. ListBox and ComboBox have the data binding capabilities built in. However, these capabilities will not work by default with the data source we have (through IKVM, we built the necessary DLL to access the H2 database from .Net environment, but the access is through the java.sql.* classes, [an example is here](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#microsoft_dot_net)). I know I need to come up with custom code that wraps the Java calls (by implementing some interfaces) but I am not sure where to start.
- I have found some examples of data binding for WinForms applications but these examples show one simple control with one data source. I would like to ask if there's a way to hook up multiple controls to a single data source (i.e. query the data source one time, and use the parts of the result in various controls; with a means to update the datasource with the changes in the UI). I do not mind writing custom classes for this purpose as well but I do not know how to start and where to go.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this page](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#microsoft_dot_net):

> An implementation of the ADO.NET interface is available in the open source project [H2Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/h2sharp/).

So you just need to use this ADO.NET provider, and data binding should work the same as with other DBMS

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I do not know how I missed that, since in my question I pointed to the exact same link (but I referred to that link regarding JDBC API usage in .Net). Thanks a lot for pointing out what I missed. I found a bug in the code, but other than that, it works fine for our purposes. It also serves well as a guide about what to do in case we need to implement such an adapter ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

H2 database has a Postgresql mode that could use ODBC to a limited extend as well which may have some help if you want ODBC via H2.